# Using Mode Command to Resize Command prompt Clears Entire Screen

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I try Writing the codes to generate random characters and I want to make the screen always at the same size but when I tried using mode command it clears all text or  you can call it entire screen
Here is the code:

```
:startprg
mode con: cols=120 lines=24
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set char=abcdeijklmnstuvwxyzABCDETUVYZ23456789^^%%_`^^%%_`^^%%_`^^%%_`^^%%_`☺☻♥♦♣♠◘•○☺☻♥♦♣♠◘♂♀q7•-6○Z♂n¡*     /*-+@#$*()_=-=+       
set count=0
set hla=0

:Number
set hla=120

set /a length=-1 + !hla!

:Loop
set /a count+=1
set /a rand=%Random%%%61
set buffer=!buffer!!char:~%rand%,1!
if !count! leq !length! goto Loop

title ^!buffer!
echo ^!buffer!
set /a length+=1

endlocal
goto startprg
```

Please help me I'm on Windows 10 and I don't know how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Currently each time you `goto :startprg` you re`set` the mode. Simply move the label to after `mode con:` in order to initiate it only once. So it should be:

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=120 lines=24
:startprg
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

So the full code would be as:

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=120 lines=24

:startprg
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set char=abcdeijklmnstuvwxyzABCDETUVYZ23456789^^%%_`^^%%_`^^%%_`^^%%_`^^%%_`☺☻♥♦♣♠◘•○☺☻♥♦♣♠◘♂♀q7•-6○Z♂n¡*     /*-+@#$*()_=-=+       
set count=0
set hla=0

:Number
set hla=120

set /a length=-1 + !hla!

:Loop
set /a count+=1
set /a rand=%Random%%%61
set buffer=!buffer!!char:~%rand%,1!
if !count! leq !length! goto Loop

title ^!buffer!
echo ^!buffer!
set /a length+=1

endlocal
goto startprg
```